# How to address nested list items properly

Tags: python, nested-lists

I have obviously troubles understanding basic list functionalities: There are two
code snippets - both working fine - addressing nested list items in different ways.

## Part1

```
List_A=[['A','B','C'],['D','E','F']]  
List_B=[]  
for col in range(len(List_A)):  
    List_B=List_B+[[]]  
    for item in List_A:  
        >List_B[col]=List_B[col]+List_A[item][col]  
print(List_B)
```

## Part2

```
List_D=[]  
List_C=[['A','B','C'],['D','E','F']]  
List_D=List_C[0][2]+List_C[1][1]  
print(List_D)
```

I am not getting why to address the nested list items in **Part1** and **Part2** differently. **Part1** addresses
the list item `[item[nested item]]` while part two addresses the nested items `[item][nested item]`.
When **Part1** is complemented like `List_A[item[col]]` i get the error `'List indices must be integers not strings'`. Can you help me understand the difference?

Comment: *When part1 is complemented like List_A[item[col]] error 'List indices must be integers not strings'.* `item[col]` is a string, hence. apart from that error, I don't really understand what you're asking

Comment: Your desription of what part1 does is not really correct,  Try printing out what `item` is inside the loop and see if that helps you.  The best way to understand the code is often to just step through it and see what it does.